# Why is it so difficult to use geometric methods to construct weight one modular forms?

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory, modular-forms, automorphic-forms

I am trying to understand why it is that geometric methods of constructing modular forms of weight one for $SL(2,\mathbb Z)$ fail. I have a relatively rudimentary understanding of it, but it would be helpful if someone could give me an overview?

Comment: What do you mean by "geometric method of constructing modular forms"?

Answer (score 2):

There are no nonzero modular forms of odd weight for $SL(2,\mathbb{Z})$. Because of the invariance of a modular form $f$ under the action of $−id$, where $id$ is the identity matrix in $SL(2,\mathbb{Z})$, it follows that $f$ of odd weight $m$ is zero:  $f(z) =(−1)^mf(z)$. So we may assume that $m=2k$ is even. It is easy to see that for $k=0$ there are only the constant modular forms. There is also no modular form of weight $2$ for $SL(2,\mathbb{Z})$, and no modular form of neagtive weight. For each $k>2$ however we have nontrivial modular forms of weight $2k$.

On the other hand, the situation is different in general for congruence subgroups $\Gamma(N)$ of $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$. There is a large literature on this subject 
(see also Deligne-Serre construction of Galois representations, geometric constructions using $\ell$-adic cohomology of modular curves $X(N)$, and other topics).

Comment: I suspect that the actual question was supposed to allow congruence subgroups. In which case, the methods for constructing Galois representations via the etale cohomology of modular curves only work in weights $k \ge 2$. So there is a genuinely interesting question here that neither answer addresses. However, since the OP was last seen in December, 2014, there's probably not much reason for giving an answer.

Answer (score 2):

If $\Gamma$ is subgroup of $ \mathrm{SL}_2(\Bbb{Z})$ which $-\mathrm{id}\notin \Gamma$, then there is weight $1$ modular form such as

$$ \mathbb{G}_1(z)=\frac{1}{2}L(0,\chi)+\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\left(\sum_{d|n}\chi(d)d\right)e^{2\pi i n z}$$

over $ \Gamma(4)$. where $\chi:(\Bbb{Z}/n\Bbb{Z})^{\times}\to \Bbb{C}$ is Dirichlet character. but if $\Gamma=\mathrm{SL}(2,\Bbb{Z})$, there is no modular form of weight $1$.